# Cannot return opened realm instance in writing state in a resolved promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, realm

I am trying to create a realm helper function to return an open and writeable realm instance...I am not sure why this is not working?  I am getting error:

> Error: Can only delete objects within a transaction.

This indicates that the (realm) in the resolve is closing/becoming unwritable when it is returned via the resolve.

```
import * as Realm from "realm";

// Realm object is returned but is not ready for writing?.
export const RealmHelper = {
    realmWrite(schema: any) : Promise<Realm> {
        const promise = new Promise<Realm>((resolve, reject) => {
            Realm.open({schema: schema}).then((realm: Realm) => {
                realm.write(() => {
                    resolve(realm);
                });
            }).catch((error) => reject(error));
        });
        return promise;
    }
};
```

I am calling the helper with:

```
    return RealmHelper.realmWrite([UserSchema]).then((realm: Realm) => {
       realm.delete(this); // from within a UserSchema
       return true;
    });
```

This more ugly and verbose way works fine:

```
    function deleteUser() {
        const promise = new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
            Realm.open({schema: [UserSchema]}).then((realm: Realm) => {
                realm.write(() => {
                    console.log("deleting: user ", this);
                    realm.delete(this);
                    resolve(true);
                });
            }).catch((error) => reject(error));
        });
        return promise;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding a callback that would be called before the resolve in the write callback.  Here's the solution that works for me:

```
export const RealmHelper = {
    realmWrite<T>(schema: any, func: (realm: Realm) => T) : Promise<T> {
        const promise = new Promise<T>((resolve, reject) => {
            Realm.open({schema: schema}).then((realm: Realm) => {
                realm.write(() => {
                    resolve(func(realm));
                });
            }).catch((error) => reject(error));
        });
        return promise;
    }
};
```

Can be called using:

```
RealmHelper.realmWrite([UserSchema], (realm) => realm.create<User>("User", this));
```

Answer (score 2):

When you resolve the promise in this block

```
Realm.open({schema: schema}).then((realm: Realm) => {
    realm.write(() => {
        resolve(realm);
    });
}).catch((error) => reject(error));
```

you're also immediately exiting the scope in which the write transaction happen. Consider this:

```
Realm.open({schema: schema}).then((realm: Realm) => {
    realm.write(() => {
        console.log("before resolve");
        resolve(realm);
        console.log("after resolve");
    });
}).catch((error) => reject(error));

// use the helper
return RealmHelper.realmWrite([UserSchema]).then((realm: Realm) => {
   console.log("before delete");
   realm.delete(this); // from within a UserSchema
   console.log("after delete");
   return true;
});

// OUTPUT:
before resolve
after resolve
before delete
after delete
```

I haven't tested this code, but I expect you'll see something like it.

Comment: Doesn't `.then` mean we already have a resolved promise? Do you mind mentioning the need for `resolve` in the `.then` function? I'm still trying to get my head around promises and in particular there usage with Realm.